# Excel VBA: how to find a description from an AD-group

Tags: excel, vba, active-directory

I've browsed this site many times for answers and this is my first question. Great community here!

For a project I need to make an Excel sheet that suggests new Active directory groups based on their current active directory groups. For this I need the description field of the current active directory group (this is a mandatory field in our organization).

So I already have a script that can verify the existence of a Group by marking it with a colour. It's only 1 step of a multi step problem.
This doesn't retrieve the description information. And I have not found a working solution on the internet so far that I also understood.
A problem that might make it more complex is that the groups are in different Containers. This make the distinguished name prefix inconsistent.

Any help would be welcome.
Jeroen

Code so far. This reads ADgroups from column D (starting with D2) and searches it in active directory. Then it marks a cell with the colour green if it was found.

```
Sub ValidateGroupName()

Dim objController
Dim objGCController
Dim objConnection
Dim objCommand
Dim strADPath
Dim objRecordSet
Dim objFields

Dim Y As Integer
Dim GroupName As String
Dim ActSheet As String
Dim Descriptionname As String

ActSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

' Set up AD connection

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConnection.Open "Provider=ADsDSOObject;"

Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection

Set objController = GetObject("GC:")

' Get record from AD

For Each objGCController In objController
    strADPath = objGCController.ADspath
    'strADDescription = objGCController.ADspath
Next


Y = 0
Do

GroupName = Sheets(ActSheet).Range("D2").Offset(Y, 0).Value

    objCommand.CommandText = _
    "<" & strADPath & ">;(&(objectClass=Group)" & _
         "(cn=" & GroupName & "));distinguishedName;subtree"
         

objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 50000
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute
    
' What to do with results?
If objRecordSet.RecordCount = 0 Then
'change color of a cell to red
Sheets(ActSheet).Range("E2").Offset(Y, 0).Interior.Color = 255
Else
' change color of a cell to green
Sheets(ActSheet).Range("E2").Offset(Y, 0).Interior.Color = 7138816
End If

Y = Y + 1

Loop Until Sheets(ActSheet).Range("D2").Offset(Y, 0).Value = ""

' Close AD connection
    objConnection.Close

End Sub
```

I hope I'm on the right track, but a different approach might be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, add 'description' property to your query :

```
objCommand.CommandText = _
    "<" & strADPath & ">;(&(objectClass=Group)" & _
         "(cn=" & GroupName & "));distinguishedName;subtree;Description"
```

second, get property value if group exist and write it beside group cell for example :

```
If objRecordSet.RecordCount = 0 Then
'change color of a cell to red
Sheets(ActSheet).Range("E2").Offset(Y, 0).Interior.Color = 255
Else
' change color of a cell to green
Sheets(ActSheet).Range("E2").Offset(Y, 0).Interior.Color = 7138816
Sheets(ActSheet).Range("E2").Offset(Y, 1).text = objRecordset.Fields("Description")
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwser. It seems to be the correct answer, but unfortunately it seems our company blocks this request.

Objcommand>Fields>Item 1>OriginalValue
        : OriginalValue : <Current Recordset does not support updating. This may be a limitation of the provider, or of the selected locktype.> : Variant

Comment: `Field.Value` not `.Original Value` ?

Comment: maybe objRecordset.moveFirst before getting value ? strange error as we don't update anything.